# Finding a known object with OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm new in OpenCV. I'm using OpenCV - 2.4.12 on visual studio 2013, windows 10. I'm trying to create a program that will take 2 images as input and try to find a similar block of 1st image in the 2nd image. by finding features and Homography.. basically I'm following [This](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html%22This%22) tutorial. and implemented the code successfully. so I wanted to take things 1 step further, I wanted to crop the matched block... so, I successfully created a mask image, but when I try to bitwise_and, or similar thing, it shows the following error.

```
Unhandled exception at 0x772FD928 in OpenCVTut.exe Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0017E6C0.
```

I've tried googling a lot... but couldn't find any solution. following is the code, and the images I'm using and the mask that I generated..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\features2d\features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2\calib3d\calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2\features2d\features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2\nonfree\nonfree.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main() {
    Mat imgObject = cvLoadImage("E:/opencv/images/Experiments/target.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat imgScene = cvLoadImage("E:/opencv/images/Experiments/source.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    if (!imgObject.data || !imgScene.data) {
        cout << "Error reading images" << endl;

        return -1;
    }

    int minHessian = 400;
    SurfFeatureDetector detector(minHessian);
    vector<KeyPoint> keyPointsObject;
    vector<KeyPoint> keyPointsScene;

    detector.detect(imgObject, keyPointsObject);
    detector.detect(imgScene, keyPointsScene);

    SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
    Mat descriptorObject;
    Mat descriptorScene;

    extractor.compute(imgObject, keyPointsObject, descriptorObject);
    extractor.compute(imgScene, keyPointsScene, descriptorScene);

    FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
    vector<DMatch> matches;
    matcher.match(descriptorObject, descriptorScene, matches);

    double maxDist = 0;
    double minDist = 100;

    for (int i = 0; i < descriptorObject.rows; i++) {
        double dist = matches[i].distance;

        if (dist > maxDist) maxDist = dist;
        if (dist < minDist) minDist = dist;
    }

    cout << "-- Max dist : " << maxDist << endl;
    cout << "-- Min dist : " << minDist << endl;

    vector<DMatch> goodMatches;
    for (int i = 0; i < descriptorObject.rows; i++) {
        if (matches[i].distance < 3 * minDist) {
            goodMatches.push_back(matches[i]);
        }
    }

    /*Mat imgMatches;
    drawMatches(imgObject, keyPointsObject, imgScene, keyPointsScene,
        goodMatches, imgMatches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
        vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);*/

    vector<Point2f> obj;
    vector<Point2f> scene;

    for (int i = 0; i < goodMatches.size(); i++) {
        obj.push_back(keyPointsObject[goodMatches[i].queryIdx].pt);
        scene.push_back(keyPointsScene[goodMatches[i].trainIdx].pt);
    }

    Mat H = findHomography(obj, scene, CV_RANSAC);

    vector<Point2f> objCorners(4);
    objCorners[0] = cvPoint(0, 0);
    objCorners[1] = cvPoint(imgObject.cols, 0);
    objCorners[2] = cvPoint(imgObject.cols, imgObject.rows);
    objCorners[3] = cvPoint(0, imgObject.rows);

    vector<Point2f> sceneCorners(4);
    perspectiveTransform(objCorners, sceneCorners, H);

    line(imgScene, sceneCorners[0], sceneCorners[1], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
    line(imgScene, sceneCorners[1], sceneCorners[2], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
    line(imgScene, sceneCorners[2], sceneCorners[3], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
    line(imgScene, sceneCorners[3], sceneCorners[0], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);

    Mat mask = Mat::zeros(imgScene.rows, imgScene.cols, CV_8UC3);
    vector< vector<Point> > contours;
    vector< Vec4i > hierarchy;

    Mat coun;
    imgScene.copyTo(coun);
    findContours(coun, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    Scalar color(255, 255, 255);
    drawContours(mask, contours, 0, color, CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy);

    Mat element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(2, 2), Point(0, 0));
    dilate(mask, mask, element);
    erode(mask, mask, element);

    Mat res(imgScene.rows, imgScene.cols, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    bitwise_and(imgScene, mask, res);

    namedWindow("Good Matches & Object detection", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Good Matches & Object detection", mask);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Scene]
Scene

[image: Target]

Target

[image: Generated Mask]
Mask

So, can anyone please explain the error... and what I need to do to solve it..

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can start by checking the option to break when this exception is thrown, and see why it's thrown for yourself.

Comment: @StoryTeller. tried that too... if it would make much sense I wouldn't be asking here... :p :') ... like I said... I'm quite new in opencv, or more likely computer vision.

Comment: please find the line of code where the error occurs. Use debugger or std::cout a unique message once in a while.

Comment: @Micka... I'm pretty sure the error is in 
"bitwise_and(imgScene, mask, res);"

this line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs at line:

```
bitwise_and(imgScene, mask, res);
```

because the two matrices have different type: `imgScene` is a `CV_8UC1` matrix and `mask` is a `CV_8UC3`.

Since a mask is usually just a binary image, that can be safely represented with a single channel matrix, you can fix your code making `mask` a `CV_8UC1` matrix:

```
Mat mask = Mat::zeros(imgScene.rows, imgScene.cols, CV_8UC1); // Instead of CV_8UC3
```

Comment: Thanks man... you are a life saver :D sorry for the late response, messed up some configuration... had to fix that... :) ... Really appreciate your help... :)